# Incorrect syntax error in join query sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query.

```
with getstock as 
(
    select 
        a.bomparent, a.bomchild, a.bomqty, a.bompos, a.baltmethod, a.bomissue
    from 
        bom a
    where 
        bomparent = 'QZ10-0262601' and baltmethod = '1'

    union all

    select 
        parent.bomparent, parent.bomchild, parent.bomqty, parent.bompos, parent.baltmethod, parent.bomissue 
    from 
        getstock as a
    inner join 
        bom as parent, stock as s on parent.bomparent = a.bomchild
    where 
        parent.baltmethod = '1' and parent.bomparent = s.stocknum
)
select  *
from getstock
```

When I run it, I get the following error.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use multiple tables in `JOIN`. It's possible in `FROM`, but I won't suggest that. That's the old-style `JOIN` syntax. You should rewrite your query using explicit `JOIN`:

```
with getstock as 
(
    select 
        a.bomparent, a.bomchild, a.bomqty, a.bompos, a.baltmethod, a.bomissue
    from 
        bom a
    where 
        bomparent = 'QZ10-0262601' and baltmethod = '1'

    union all

    select 
        parent.bomparent, parent.bomchild, parent.bomqty, parent.bompos, parent.baltmethod, parent.bomissue 
    from 
        getstock as a
    inner join 
        bom as parent on parent.bomparent = a.bomchild
    inner join 
        stock as s on parent.bomparent = s.stocknum
    where 
        parent.baltmethod = '1'
)
select  *
from getstock
```

For more reading: [Avoid using old-style `JOIN` syntax.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1):

You can also re-write your query with proper joins for select with union all as below :

```
SELECT        bomparent, bomchild, bomqty, bompos, baltmethod, bomissue
FROM            bom AS a
WHERE        (bomparent = 'QZ10-0262601') AND (baltmethod = '1')

    union all


SELECT        bom.bomparent, bom.bomchild, bom.bomqty, bom.bompos, bom.baltmethod, bom.bomissue
FROM            getstock INNER JOIN
                         bom ON getstock.bomchild = bom.bomparent INNER JOIN
                         stock ON bom.bomparent = stock.stocknum
WHERE        (bom.baltmethod = N'1')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with getstock as 
(
    select a.bomparent, a.bomchild, a.bomqty, a.bompos,
    a.baltmethod, a.bomissue
    from bom a
    where bomparent = 'QZ10-0262601' and baltmethod = '1'
    union all
    select parent.bomparent, parent.bomchild, parent.bomqty,
    parent.bompos,  parent.baltmethod, parent.bomissue 
    from getstock as a
    inner join bom as parent
     on parent.bomparent = a.bomchild
    inner join stock as s
     parent.bomparent = s.stocknum
   where parent.baltmethod = '1' 
)
select  *
from getstock
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work but its not following best practices. Always use Join condition properly(INNER JOIN ...ON).

```
with getstock as 
(
    select a.bomparent, a.bomchild, a.bomqty, a.bompos, a.baltmethod, a.bomissue
    from bom a
    where bomparent = 'QZ10-0262601' and baltmethod = '1'
    union all

    select parent.bomparent, parent.bomchild, parent.bomqty, parent.bompos, parent.baltmethod, parent.bomissue 
    from getstock as a,
        bom as parent, 
        stock as s  
    where parent.bomparent = a.bomchild and
        parent.baltmethod = '1' and parent.bomparent = s.stocknum
)
select  * from getstock
```

Comment: And you're **NOT** using `INNER JOIN` in your example ..... this is even worse than the OP's question ...

Comment: I know, But this is a way of soving the issues. That's all i am trying to convey. I have already mentioned that its not a good way to do in this way.